# How to stretch an HTML table to 100% of the browser window height?

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

I'm using a table to design the layout of my web page. I want the table to fill the page even if it doesn't contain much content. Here's the CSS I'm using:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

And I place something like this in the page code:

```
<table id="container">
<tr>
<td>
...
```

This works for Opera 9, but not for Firefox 2 or Internet Explorer 7. Is there a simple way to make this solution work for all popular browsers?

(Adding `id="container"` to `td` doesn't help.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the `height` property instead of the `min-height` property when setting `#container`. Once the data gets too big, the table will automatically grow.

Answer (score 20):

Try using this:

```
html, body    {
  height: 100%;
}
```

So besides making the table's height to 100%, you also should have to make sure that the html'd and body's height are also 100%, so it will stretch properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in Javascript/JQuery.

```
window_height = $(window).height();
$('#container').css('min-height', window_height);
```