# how to give a table 100% height?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stretch an HTML table to 100% of the browser window height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90049/how-to-stretch-an-html-table-to-100-of-the-browser-window-height)

as the title says , how can i get my table element to have 100% height even though the table is not having enough content to fill the 100% height of the page

how can i do that? thank you in advance!

Comment: This isn't for some tabular layout, is it? Because if it is, [***You're doing it Wrong™***](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html)

Comment: use a div if you wanna add a background? which it seems your asking about

Comment: use javascript to get the screen size and resolution and then assign the height to the table based on it.

Answer (score 4):

Possible duplicate of: [How to stretch an HTML table to 100% of the browser window height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90049/how-to-stretch-an-html-table-to-100-of-the-browser-window-height)

I made a jsFiddle with an example of how to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/mkZ74/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the table to a div and setting the div display style to block ,  as  style="display: block;". This would ensure that your div expands to maximum content , which in your case is table.